# Calculating thermodynamic quantities for hydrogenation of iron nitride

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, equilibrium, free-energy

> **HW#6.3** If the reaction
>
> $$\ce{Fe2N(s) + 3/2 H2(g) <=> 2 Fe(s) + NH3(g)}$$
>
> comes to an equilibrium at a total pressure of $\pu{1 bar},$ analysis of the gas shows that at $\pu{700 K}$ and $\pu{800 K},$ $p_\ce{NH3}/p_\ce{H2}$ are $2.165$ and $1.083,$ respectively, if only $\ce{H2(g)}$ was initially in the gas phase and $\ce{Fe2N(s)}$ was in excess:
>
> **a**. Calcualte $K_p$ at $\pu{700 K}$ and $\pu{800 K}.$
> **b**. Calculate $Δ_\mathrm{r}S^\circ$ at $\pu{700 K}$ and $\pu{800 K}$ and $Δ_\mathrm{r}H^\circ$ assuming that it is independent of temperature.
> **c**. Calculate $Δ_\mathrm{r}G^\circ$ for this reaction at $\pu{298 K}.$

At first I ignored the excess data, then I assumed that the pressure exerted by the solids is null and adding partial pressures I got an answer (sum of pressure of gases equals 1).

The problem is that part **a** in the book gives answer $K_p = 1.777$ at $\pu{700 K}$ which I think is wrong. Please help.

Comment: I get 3.85 at 700K

Comment: I got that too but the book says 1.777 guess I can't trust the back of the book now ,using Castellan Physical Chemistry